# How to call a handler from another handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating session variables in a handler

I am accessing that variable in other handlers and using it.

Now if that session variable is null

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"] == null)
             // call the other handler which sets session
```

how can i make call to another handler so that it sets the session variable again?

Comment: Can you put the logic in a method which is accessible by both handlers?

Comment: upvoted, Thanks i will put those methods in a class file and access them.
Just wanted to know if there is a way i can call handler cos that will avoid more rework parts in the code if i can just trigger the other handler